# How do I get a small movable pop up window like this

Tags: android, kotlin

I am wondering how I create a small pop up window like my image. It is Samsungs timer window. I am wondering what it is. Is it an activity, fragment, something else? Any idea how I would do it? I still want to see whatever was on the screen at the time, just with the popup. [image: popup]

Comment: It's called floating bubbles or chat heads...  If want to implement in your popup... Use draggable view...